# Rails 3 sum two attributes and assign to another on same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, attributes, sum

I have a Reports model with two attributes :big_expenses and :small_expenses. I want to know if it's possible to sum these two up and assign the sum to another attribute called :total. If so, how does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Reports model you could have a callback that calls a method to sum up the two attributes right before it is saved.

Example:

```
class Report

before_save :total_big_and_small_expenses


def total_big_and_small_expenses
  self.total = self.big_expenses + self.small_expenses
end
```

Comment: Thanks, being so new at this, could you explain how I would use this in the show to display the :total attribute?

Comment: In the show, I'm assuming your talking about the view.  If you created a Report in your controller something like report = Report.create!(:small_expenses => 5, :big_expenses => 100).  You should be able to just say report.total in the view and get the total after adding the code in the model that I mentioned.

Comment: Cool, thanks. That's probably it. I'm getting an error after doing that the method 'total' is undefined though. Any thoughts on that, probably user error.

Comment: Does your reports table have a total column?  If not you need to run a migration to add one to the reports table.  If you are unsure, check your schema file.  You should see a big_expenses, small_expenses, and total attributes.